# Pick image src for parent folder of index

Tags: html, image, subdirectory, organization

I have this folder setup:[image]
If I'm render a template from /views with the url `mydomain.com/user/0/app/0` and I insert a `<img>` with image 1 from /uploads, I tried to set the *src* like this:

```
<img src="/uploads/image1.png">
```

but the navigator rewrite the url and set this:

```
<img src="mydomain.com/uploads/image1.png">
```

How can I prevent the navigator rewrite this route and access to the correct file?

NOTE: I'm using Slim v3 if it's useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this? <img src="../uploads/image1.png">

Comment: With that, chrome show me this: mydomain.com/user/0/uploads/image1.png

Comment: I think the problem is that my vhost points to public_html folder, so I can't visualize an image from any parent folder, maybe, I don't know xD

Comment: Maybe your right XD. if all else fail transfer upload folder to public_html